# How can we send our Application Logs from Fargate [ECS] to our self-hosted ElasticSearch?

Tags: logstash, amazon-ecs, elastic-stack, aws-fargate, filebeat

Points:

1. Our Application is running on port 5000 on Fargate in ECS.
2. Our Application creates logs on a specific path in a file. eg: /Server/logs/info.log
3. Our motive is to use `filebeat` as a sidecar container to send logs to a `logstash` pipeline.

Can anyone explain how to achieve this? It would be really helpful if someone can guide me to set that up.

We want to use a sidecar container for `filebeat` with our application in the same `Task Definition`. We have our self-hosted `ElasticSearch` and `Logstash` on an EC2 in the same VPC.

I've tried it by creating a `filebeat` image with my filebeat config file, it is running but not sending logs.

```
filebeat.config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: false

      #filebeat.autodiscover:
      #  providers:
      #    - type: docker
      #      hints.enabled: true
      #      hints.default_config:
      #        type: container
      #        paths:
      #          - /var/log/containers/*-${data.container.id}.log

autodiscover.providers:
  - type: docker
    templates:
      - condition.contains:
          docker.container.image: node-app
        config:
          - type: log
            paths:
              - "/mnt/logs/*.log"

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["ip:5044"]

processors:
- add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

Comment: Seeing your task definition would be helpful. Are you mapping the `/mnt/logs` path from your other container into the filebeat container?

Comment: @MarkB I'm really new in the concepts of volume binding, so i've created a bind volume of my logs directory in my task definition and attach the read permission with filebeat side-car container. It won't worked, If you can help in bind volumes or if there is a way with it, Please comment.

Comment: I can't help if you don't show all the code necessary to reproduce the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Edit your question to include your ECS task definition. I can't point out what you did wrong without seeing that. You could also use `ecs exec` to verify that the sidecar container can actually see the log files https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to do this is by using `FireLens` which is a container log router for Amazon ECS and AWS Fargate. You can use `FireLens` for Amazon ECS to use task definition parameters to route logs to plenty of destinations including `Logstash` in your case. `FireLens` works with `Fluentd` and `Fluent Bit`. Read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_firelens.html)

This will run as a `sidecar container` and you will need to add another `container` to the `containerDefinitions` of your task-definition. This also needs an update to the `logConfiguration` in your main application container to use `awsfirelens` as the `logDriver`. Example configuration:

```
"containerDefinitions":[
    {
        "essential":true,
        "image":"906394416424.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/aws-for-fluent-bit:stable",
        "name":"log_router",
        "firelensConfiguration":{
            "type":"fluentbit"
        },
    },
    {
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver":"awsfirelens",
            "options": {
                "Name":"http",
                "Host":"api.logstash.fake.domain",
                "Port":"8090",
                "Format":"json",
                "Retry_Limit": "2"
            }
         ...
    }
]
```

See the example config [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/firelens-taskdef.html), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/firelens-example-taskdefs.html) & [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-firelens-examples/blob/mainline/examples/fluent-bit/logstash/task-definition.json) (specifically for logstash).

Make sure the task IAM role Amazon Resource Name (ARN) contains the permissions needed for the task to route the logs.

Hope it helps.